# SQL Server Non Clustered Index Compression

Tags: sql-server, index, compression

I'm struggling to find out the answer, we currently use compression on all our data warehouse tables, which has improved performance and also greatly reduced the storage space used.

I've only recently realised, that we aren't compressing any of our non-clustered indexes. Should we also be doing this? Are there any gotchas that we should be aware of?

Comment: Please check this link, could be helpful - https://sqlperformance.com/2017/01/sql-performance/compression-effect-on-performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've only recently realised, that we aren't compressing any of our
>   non-clustered indexes. Should we also be doing this? Are there any
>   gotchas that we should be aware of?

The main question here is, do you want to save space & memory usage at the cost of more cpu cycles? This is something we will not be able to answer for you.

Since you are able to compress the clustered indexes, no other restrictions noted in [Considerations for When You Use Row and Page Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression?view=sql-server-2017) are possible limitations.

You could always run the [sp_estimate_data_compression_savings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-estimate-data-compression-savings-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) procedure to calculate the gains you could get from compressing the nonclustered indexes. See [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2381/sql-server-data-compression-storage-savings-for-all-tables/) for a solution for every table in your data warehouse.

Speaking of data warehouses, you could also take a look at (clustered / nonclustered) [columnstore indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017) and see if they are a fit for your (fact) tables.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the unique constraint gotcha? AFAIK, there are no special concerns as one can specify data compression for unique constraints and change the option for existing unique constraints with `ALTER INDEX`.

Comment: @DanGuzman you are right, it is not a concern. Guess I executed some unneeded changes in the past when compressing tables. Thanks a lot for pointing that out

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This is essentially how I thought it would behave, but wasn't sure. We've had compression turned on with all our data warehouse tables for quite some time. Whilst there is in theory a performance hit on the CPU side of things for decompressing the file, since making the move to compressing all tables, we've seen an improvement in the overall speed of things, obviously due to quicker disk reads, smaller memory foot print, etc. I'm going to start applying to same logic to our non clustered indexes, as we don't currently have any cpu constraints.